# C++ Amp debug using the actual GPGPU

Tags: c#, c++, debugging, gpgpu, c++-amp

I'm trying to get started with C++ Amp as a DLL, called from a C# application, and debugging GPU code has been rather difficult.  I can debug using the emulated reference card (directd_3d ref by default), but I can't get Visual Studio (2012) to debug using that actual NVIDIA card.  The reason it's a problem is that the ref card takes orders of magnitude more time to run (half an hour vs. seconds in this case).

I found some indication that NSight used to support this, but that was back in 3.X, and I have 5.x

Any ideas out there on how to debug with the physical GPGPU?